# UIKit Dynamics with existing affine transform

Tags: ios, uikit, cgaffinetransform

I have a view that has some scale transformations. And when I apply some UIKit Dynamics on it, it zeroes them out. /:
How can I keep the existing transformation on the view while having it jump around? :P

Thanks. :)

Comment: Good question, I have been trying to hack this all evening :-) Please post back when you have findings.

Comment: I haven't run across this myself yet, but one potential strategy is to use an extra container view that you apply the UIKit Dynamics to, then the view you want to scale is a subview of that container view (centered within it) and now you should be able to apply whatever transforms you want onto the view without them interfering with UIKit Dynamics.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at UIDynamicAnimator's [`updateItemUsingCurrentState`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDynamicAnimator/updateItemUsingCurrentState%3a).

> A dynamic animator automatically reads the initial state (position and rotation) of each dynamic item you add to it, and then takes responsibility for updating the item’s state. If you **actively change the state of a dynamic item after you’ve added it to a dynamic animator**, call this method to ask the animator to read and incorporate the new state.

So anytime you change the transform after the item you're transforming has been added to an animator, just call `updateItemUsingCurrentState` right after.

```
id <UIDynamicItem> dynamicItem; // whatever your item is, probably a UIView
UIGravityBehavior *behavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[dynamicItem]];
UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view]; // or however you're getting your animator

[animator addBehavior:behavior];

view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
[animator updateItemUsingCurrentState:view];
```

Comment: Tah, can't believe I missed that... Thanks mate! :)

Comment: is this apply for `scale`? As the document mentioned the initial state(position and rotation), and as this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631383/uidynamicitem-update-transform-manually) said, "UIDynamicAnimator only supports rotation and position, not scale (or any other type of affine transform)."

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tutorial,http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial.
The author said,we can’t use a transform to scale your object while it is under the control of dynamics.
I hope the article could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way around this was to just apply the `UIKitDynamics` behaviours to a container view and apply the scaling/transforms to a subview within that container.

This way you can also animate the transform while still applying the dynamic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711188/1153630) answer, I have a solution: update the transform on every frame of the animation

```
let attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: item, attachedTo: item) // Workaround - attach the item to itself
attachment?.action = { () in
    item.transform = item.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
}

animator.addBehavior(attachment)
```

Comment: can you tell me ,what is animater  .

Comment: It’s your `UIDynamicAnimator` instance