# UIDynamicItem update transform manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

I know that external change to `center`, `bounds` and `transform` will be ignored after `UIDynamicItem`s init.

But I need to manually change the `transform` of `UIView` that in `UIDynamicAnimator` system.

Every time I change the `transform`, it will be covered at once.

So any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any time you change one of the animated properties, you need to call `[dynamicAnimator updateItemUsingCurrentState:item]` to let the dynamic animator know you did it. It'll update it's internal representation to match the current state.

---

EDIT: I see from your code below that you're trying to modify the scale. `UIDynamicAnimator` only supports rotation and position, not scale (or any other type of affine transform). It unfortunately takes over `transform` in order to implement just rotation. I consider this a bug in `UIDynamicAnimator` (but then I find much of the implementation of UIKit Dynamics to classify as "bugs").

What you can do is modify your bounds (before calling `updateItem...`) and redraw yourself. If you need the performance of an affine transform, you have a few options:

- Move your actual drawing logic into a `CALayer` or subview and modify its scale (updating your `bounds` to match if you need collision behaviors to still work).
- Instead of attaching your view to the behavior, attach a proxy object (just implement `<UIDyanamicItem>` on an `NSObject`) that passes the transform changes to you. You can then combine the requested transform with your own transform.

Comment: I did `updateItemUsingCurrentState:` right after `myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(originTransform, 1.2, 1.2);`, and the scale shows then get back immediately.:(

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the .action property of the UIDynamicBehavior to set your desired transform at every tick of the animation.

```
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:item attachedToAnchor:item.center];
attachment.damping = 0.8f;
attachment.frequency = 0.8f;
attachment.action = ^{
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = item.transform;
    item.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, 1.2, 1.2)
};
```

You would need to add logic within the action block to determine when the scale should be changed, and by how much, otherwise your view will always be at 120%.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this (I think we should call it bug) is to override the transform property of the UIView used. Something like this:

```
override var transform: CGAffineTransform {
    set (value) {

    }
    get {
        return super.transform
    }
}

var ownTransform: CGAffineTransform. {
    didSet {
        super.transform = ownTransform
    }
}
```

It's a kind of a hack, but it works fine, if you don't use rotation in UIKitDynamics.