# UIKit Dynamics doesn't allow me to animate a UIView's centre

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uikit-dynamics

I have a `UIView` which is attached to a `UICollisionBehavior`. I'm trying to animate its center when a new location is tapped on the screen, but it appears using this block of code is not the way to do it:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [self.mainCharacter setCenter:location];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Can anyone suggest a more UIKitDynamics friendly way of doing this?

Thanks.

***UPDATE***

So the first part of my question was similar to the one posted and a possible duplicate, however, although technically it solved the issue in the first part of this question, it does seem to interfere with how collision testing in `UICollisionBehavior`.

The second part of this question was to ask if there was a better way of doing this. I assumed it would be possible to accelerate a `UIDynamicItem` at a speed over a given time using `UIPushBehavior` but it seems to be constant.

Can anyone recommend how to use a `UIPushBehavior` to do the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIKit Dynamics with existing affine transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338607/uikit-dynamics-with-existing-affine-transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UIKit Dynamics, when you want to animate changing the center, you'd add a `UISnapBehavior` to your `UIDynamicAnimator` (removing any prior snap behavior first). For example, create a property for the `UISnapBehavior`, and then your tap gesture recognizer can snap it to that point (honoring your `UICollisionBehavior`), like so:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (self.snap)
        [self.animator removeBehavior:self.snap];

    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    UISnapBehavior *snap = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.viewToAnimate snapToPoint:point];
    [self.animator addBehavior:snap];

    self.snap = snap;
}
```

You can control the "bounciness" by adjusting the `damping` property of the `UISnapBehavior`. If you don't like it rotating the view as it's snapping, you can also add a `UIDynamicItemBehavior` with `allowsRotation` set to `NO`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I tried my own method from your comment but it didn't work because I wasn't adding/removing the behaviour on each tap.